# CSS Stop a list from splitting between columns

Tags: html, css

After a bit of research I still can't find what I'm looking for and want to make sure what I want is possible.

For a site map page I have lists of links each under a h3 tag but don't want a list split between the two columns.

Any clues?

Thanks

**The CSS**

```
    .info-col{
    max-width:720px;
    columns:350px 2;
    -webkit-columns:350px 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-columns:350px 2; /* Firefox */
    }

    .info-blob{
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="info-col">
  <div class="info-blob">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc dignissim risus id</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cras ornare tristique</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vivamus vestibulum nulla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent placerat risus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info-blob">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc dignissim risus id</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cras ornare tristique</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vivamus vestibulum nulla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent placerat risus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauri</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Nunc dignissim risus id</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cras ornare tristique</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Vivamus vestibulum nulla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Praesent placerat risus</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info-blob">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc dignissim risus id</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cras ornare tristique</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vivamus vestibulum nulla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent placerat risus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="info-blob">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Vivamus vestibulum nulla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent placerat risus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aliquam tincidunt mauri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nunc dignissim risus id</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cras ornare tristique</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vivamus vestibulum nulla</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Praesent placerat risus</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want it to be a single list in the markup, but still split up in multiple columns?

Comment: i don't want a list split between two columns, I want multiple lists one for each section of the site.

Comment: What you want? jsfiddle for your code : http://jsfiddle.net/LU26m/1/

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Your current code outputs in two columns http://jsfiddle.net/jxWcm/ Can you better explain the problem?

Comment: Nice, didn't know CSS has columns feature too:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `column-break-inside` on `.info-blob`:

```
.info-blob {
    -webkit-column-break-inside : avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside : avoid;
    column-break-inside : avoid;
}
```

As an alternative, and if you want it to be cross-browser, replace your CSS by :

```
.info-blob {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This code won't work on most browsers:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/
As far as I know, it'll only work on Opera.

Comment: You beauty, I knew it would be a simple fix if it could be sorted! Cheers

Comment: It only works in chrome :( is there another way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: @WissamEl-Kik It works under Chrome, [and should work](http://caniuse.com/#search=Columns) for IE10+ and Firefox

Comment: Thanks there is enough here for me to wiggle it all about and achieve what I need. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `break-inside:avoid` (and related vendor-prefixed versions) on the `info-blob` containers.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LU26m/2/) with the Webkit prefix - I'm not familiar with the exact one for `-moz-` but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out ;)